# Internal Storage Dying? (S.M.A.R.T. equivalent?)

Tags: adb, root-access, diagnostics

I suspect the Internal Storage on my device is failing.  How can I confirm?

If this were a computer, I would check the S.M.A.R.T. data for each storage device.  I am looking for something similar.

Misc:

- My device was released over three years ago. I'm running a Marshmallow, custom stock ROM, rooted with Magisk, and with Xposed installed.
- I recently wiped my device and reinstalled the custom ROM.
- When requesting `root`, MagiskManager often crashes and `logcat` reports: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1034)`
- I occasionally see other `I/O error` messages fly by on `logcat`
- From recovery, the `e2fsck` / `fsck.f2fs` commands report no filesystem errors.

Comment: You probably want to check for bad blocks. See e.g.: [How do I check bad sector on my android with ADB recovery mode?](/q/137223/16575) // [How do you test the disk integrity of your Android tablet's file system?](/q/26588/16575) // probably some more candidates [in this list](/search?q=bad+block).